# starting a class in a fragment

Tags: java, android

So I haven't seen any question like this and I have a problem I don't know how to start the other class from the fragment. I have been trying all day and I still can't find the answer. First of all how do I start my imageadapter class and how the hell can I write additional methods into the class and then execute them in the fragment class?

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new imageadapter(getContext()));
    }


}
```

but why does this then not work ?

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);


    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
    GridView gridView = (GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new imageadapter(this));
}
```

I still get errors by the words this and the setAdapter.

Comment: What are the errors?  Best thing to do is run a build, and copy and paste the errors into your question.  Also a terminology thing, classes are not "started".  Your question as written is quite vague, and if taken literally (how do I write and then call methods?) would be best answered by a beginning Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add an `onViewCreated` method where you can do call your methods and other stuff. Here's my code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //you can call your methods and find your views in here

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateEditAppointmentActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ADD_CLIENT);
        }
    });

    coordinatorLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.upcomingLayout);
}
```